# Fitting histogram to chi2 with unknown degrees of freedom

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

Please could someone verify that the first parameter in a `scipy.stats.chi2.fit` for some data is actually the number of degrees of freedom `df`? Here is an example of what I'm checking

```
x=np.random.rand(1000)
y=stats.chi2.pdf(x,df=1)
z=np.log10(y)
# assume z is the distribution of a rv in logspace

# is this line correct for the mles?
df, loc, scale = stats.chi2.fit(z)
```

Only if I check for example something like

```
x=np.random.rand(1000)
y=stats.chi2.pdf(x,df=1.5)
z=np.log10(y)
# assume z is the distribution in logspace
df, loc, scale = stats.chi2.fit(z)
```

It returns

```
(2.686925741184449, -0.5319434585863583, 0.08411242959515701)
```

Where I am not sure if the fit is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you find something here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L1234

Comment: When you do `fit(z)` you're not fitting a sample to a chi2 distribution... the `fit` is made to fit observations to a distribution. You're fitting y-values of a transformed PDF.

Answer (score 0):

> Please could someone verify that the first parameter in a scipy.stats.chi2.fit for some data is actually the number of degrees of freedom df?

It is. But you need to pass raw observations into the `fit` method, not the log of PDF values.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = 3.7
ref = stats.chi2(df)
sample = ref.rvs(size=10000)

params = stats.chi2.fit(sample)
print(params)
res = stats.chi2(*params)

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 300)
plt.plot(x, ref.pdf(x), '-', label='original PDF')
plt.plot(x, res.pdf(x), '--', label='fitted PDF')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('PDF')
plt.legend()
```

Perhaps you meant to do:

```
x = np.random.rand(10000)
# use inverse transform sampling to draw observations chi2 with 3.5 DoF
y = stats.chi2.ppf(x, df=3.5)  # note PPF, not PDF
# z=np.log10(y)  # we don't want to log-transform before fitting
df, loc, scale = stats.chi2.fit(y)
print(df)  # 3.491224948403113
```

And for best results, fix the `loc` and `scale` parameters of the distribution before fitting, if that is appropriate for your application, e.g.

```py
df, loc, scale = stats.chi2.fit(y, floc=0, fscale=1)
loc == 0  # True
scale == 1  # True
```